# Why my content-type in response: "text/html", but i expected "application/json"?

Tags: spring, junit, http-headers, httprequest, httpresponse

I written test for my controller, and have problem with expected Content-Type.

**My Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces={"application/json; charset=UTF-8"})
        public List<GradebookCollegeStudent> getStudents() {
            gradebook = studentService.getGradebook2();
            return gradebook.getStudents();
        }
```

Like solve, i add produces, but nothing don't change.

**My Test**

```
@BeforeAll
    public static void setup() {
        
        request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
        request.setCharacterEncoding("charset=UTF-8");
        request.setContentType("application/json");
        request.addHeader("Content-Type", APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
        request.setParameter("firstname", "Chad");
        request.setParameter("lastname", "Bronson");
        request.setParameter("email_address", "chad@gmail.com");
    }
    @BeforeEach
    public void beforeEach() {
        jdbc.execute ("insert into student (id, firstname, lastname, email_address) values ('21', 'Eric', 'Robbys', 'eric@gmail.com')");
        jdbc.execute("insert into math_grade (id, student_id, grade) values (21,21,100.00)");
        jdbc.execute ("insert into science_grade (id, student_id, grade) values (21,21,100.00)");
        jdbc.execute("insert into history_grade (id, student_id, grade) values (21,21,100.00)");
            
    }
    
    @Test
    public void getStudentsHttpRequest() throws Exception {
        
        student.setFirstname("Chad");
        student.setLastname("Darby");
        student.setEmailAddress("chad.darby@luv2code_school.com");
        entitymanage.persist(student);
        entitymanage.flush();
         
        mock.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/")).andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(content().contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(2)));
                
}
```

Like solve, i set up before all tests: content type, Character Encoding, add Header, but nothing dosn't change!

My Stack Trace

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Content type expected:<application/json> but was:<text/html;charset=UTF-8>
```

In cy Console i can see

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = []
             Body = null
    Session Attrs = {}

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Content-Language:"en", Content-Type:"text/html;charset=UTF-8"]
     Content type = text/html;charset=UTF-8
             Body = <!DOCTYPE html>
```

How solve this problem ?, tnx!

Comment: There is some wrong logic. You are preparing a request in setup but never use it for perform. Instead you are using a mocked request which apparently has the content set to default value.

Comment: Yes, this logic is wrong, agree with you, what need to do, that logic was correct?

Answer (score 0):

@GetMapping is a composed annotation that acts as a shortcut for @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET).

@GetMapping is the newer annotaion. It supports consumes

Why don't you use just @GetMapping? like:

```
@GetMapping("/")
        public List<GradebookCollegeStudent> getStudents() {
            gradebook = studentService.getGradebook2();
            return gradebook.getStudents();
        }
```

Comment: Annotation does not solve the problem